# Do JMenuItem Accelerators function properly when in a frame opened by another frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, accelerator, jmenuitem

I have one frame that opens up another frame (editor).  Most of the menu accelerators don't work when opened this way, but when I run the editor frame standalone, they do work.  Should it work?

Comment: Yes they work fine.  Please provide an SSCCE.

Comment: I second the recommendation above.  For a link to the SSCCE requirements, please look here: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when you open one frame from another in java you have to start another thread or the keybindings don't work right - they all get caught by the first frame.  This makes sense.